# MongoDB - Which one is more efficient - Nested array on a document or a reference to another collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor, database-design

I am building an Instagram like application and using MongoDB. There are also albums within the app. Currently, database scheme is as follows:

```
Albums Collections:
[
  {
     albumId,
     title,
     posts:[
       {
        postId,
        title,
        imageUrl,
        comments:[
          {
            userId,
            comment,
            date
          }
        ]
        likes:[
          {
            userId,
            date
          }
        ]
       ]
     ]
   }
  ]
```

So there are double nested arrays in the album documents that raises the question of is this the right way to do it since this one document might have a very large nested array.

Is it better to create a new Collection called `Posts` and store every post under that collection and reference it to the album by `albumId`?

Many thanks

Comment: The appraoch you are looking for is called [normalization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/data-model-design/) in I highly suggest you to read the mongo docs before starting to design your collections.

Comment: Size of a document cannot exceed 16Mb. Assuming 20B per like x 10000 likes per post and 200B per comment x 1000 comments per post, your album can't have more than 40 posts. Adressing @Jankapunkt 's comment - normalisation is from SQL universe and doesn't really belong here. And although documentation is must-read it doesn't really help with design decision unless you learn it all by heart. Try to learn from people who do - it should be simpler, e.g https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1

Comment: @Alex Blex what the blogpost describes is also described in the documentation article and it is named "Normalized Datamodels" there. Please have a look at the link.

Comment: @Jankapunkt, yes, of course. The blog explains the documentation, not contradicts it. There is a subtle difference between terms "normalised data models" and "normalisation". The later is heavily used in relational data theory, implies satisfaction of one of 6 normal forms, and might be confusing to people who learn mongo db having some RDBMS background.

Comment: Okay I see your point, thank you I will try to avoid the later term in the future to avoid such confusions.